# DOM Traversal API

Tags: javascript, dom

I am tryingto get the parent of nodes. I tried these.
***Ist Approach:***

```
function update(currentElement) {

        document.getElementById("nodeNameField").value = currentElement.nodeName;
        document.getElementById("nodeTypeField").value = currentElement.nodeType;
        document.getElementById("nodeValueField").value = currentElement.nodeValue;
}

function nodeMove(direction) {

    switch (direction)
    {
     case "parentNode": if (nodeMove.currentElement.parentNode)
                          nodeMove.currentElement = nodeMove.currentElement.parentNode;
                        else
                          alert("No parent");
    } 
    update(nodeMove.currentElement);
}

window.onload = function () {

    document.getElementById("parentBtn").onclick = function () {nodeMove("parentNode")};

    nodeMove.currentElement = document.documentElement;   // HTML
    update(nodeMove.currentElement);
```

}

Since the current element is HTML, when i click on the parent button, I do get `#document` as it's parent.
[image: Pictorial Representation]
***2nd approach:***

```
if (document.createTreeWalker) {   
    function myFilter(n) { 
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; 
    }    
    var myWalker =  document.createTreeWalker(document.documentElement,NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL,myFilter, false); 
} else   
    alert("Error: Browser does not support DOM Traversal");  

function update(currentElement) {   
    window.document.testform.nodeName.value = currentElement.nodeName;   
    window.document.testform.nodeType.value = currentElement.nodeType;   
    window.document.testform.nodeValue.value = currentElement.nodeValue; 
}  
var currentElement = myWalker.currentNode;
//var currentElement = document.documentElement; 
update(currentElement);  
</script> 
<form>  
<input type="button" value="Parent"          onclick="myWalker.parentNode();update(myWalker.currentNode);">
```

In the 2nd case, i am unable to get the parent of HTML. How will I resolve it? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `myWalker` inside `if` scope, it won't be visible for outer/global scope. Move declaration over this scope like here:

```
var myWalker;
if (document.createTreeWalker) {
    function myFilter(n) {
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }
    myWalker =  document.createTreeWalker(document.documentElement,NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL,myFilter, false);
} else
alert("Error: Browser does not support DOM Traversal");

function update(currentElement) {
    window.document.testform.nodeName.value = currentElement.nodeName;
    window.document.testform.nodeType.value = currentElement.nodeType;
    window.document.testform.nodeValue.value = currentElement.nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: I dont think it will solve it even though i admit i didn't declare myWalker correctly.

Comment: Please check moving myWalker to global scope or for tests create a property in `window` object, e.g.: `window.myWalker = myWalker`. Here you have same working [jsFiddle example ](http://jsfiddle.net/j8321ssw/) I'm pretty sure, that your code runs inside some closure and the myWalker variable is not in global scope.